# Cassandra java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: out-of-memory, heap-memory, cassandra-2.0

I'm running Datastax Community Edition on Windows7 64 bit desktop PC with 8GB RAM. Running only a single node. Here allocated heap size is 1GB. While I tried to insert data(10 Milion) into a table through a Java application(Using casssandra java driver), its working fine. But when I tried to insert from an client-server program(It includes 2-3 thread initialization) then its blocking, raising a *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*  error. Noticeable point is, I checked the heap size, used memory, free memory after every insert transaction and there is enough space in heap. Also from the *Ops-center web interface* I checked the Heap size and it is never using full space ! I also tried to increase the heap size uncommenting *#MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"* from _cassandea_env.sh_ file but I got same result
Q1. What is causing this error arise?
Q2. How to overcome this
Thanks for any helpful suggestion[image: Error log]
The log file history-
[image]
[image]

Comment: I also calculated the size a row of my database table can took. It is 90 Byte per row. I tried to insert 1000 rows initially and it raises outof memory  error after inserting 367 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Its a mistake that I didn't free the cassandra connection after every transaction(In my case, insertion). After I did that now I can handle my desired transaction.